# Check arguments of secondary constructor

Tags: scala

I want to check arguments of secondary constructor, but I'm forced to call primary constructor first. One way is to put checks inside the call to `this`, but it can become ugly if conditions are complex.

```
def this(initDollars: Int, initCents: Int) = {
    this(if (initDollars >= 0 && initCents >= 0) initDollars * 100 + initCents else throw new Exception("Negative values"))
  }
```

Are there better ways to do it?

Comment: You can always check the arguments after the call. Failing that, write a function that would check the values and either throw an exception, or return a value to pass to the secondary constructor: `this(validateAndSum(initDollars, initCents))`

Comment: I really like your idea, but it works only if we have one parameter

Comment: You can have a secondary constructor taking a tuple, it's secondary anyway, class users probably won't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer the code into a method in a companion object, but why not avoid constructors all together and just use the companion object when you need validation?

```
object Example {  // To keep class & companion together
  class Foo private[Foo] (val value: Int) {}
  object Foo {
    def apply(i: Int) = if (i>=0) new Foo(i) else throw new Exception("Wrong")
    def apply(i: Int, j: Int) = {
      if (i>=0 && j>=0 && i.toLong*100+j < Int.MaxValue) new Foo(i*100+j)
      else throw new Exception("Bleh")
    }
  }
}
```

Which works like so:

```
scala> Example.Foo(-47)
java.lang.Exception: Wrong
    at Example$Foo$.apply(<console>:15)
        [...]

scala> Example.Foo(49,62)
res19: Example.Foo = Example$Foo@418c43ad

scala> res19.value
res20: Int = 4962
```

(In code not it the REPL, you don't need to wrap in `Example` for them to be companion objects; just have them in the same file.  Or you can use ^D in the REPL.)

Answer (score 2):

Why not call the primary constructor first, and check afterwards? The result is the same.

```
def this(initDollars: Int, initCents: Int) = {
    this(initDollars * 100 + initCents)
    assert(initDollars >= 0 && initCents >= 0, "Negative values")
}
```

An alternative would be a companion object with `apply`-method.

Comment: just to save some time spent on calculations for example

Comment: Seriously? I'd rather have readable code than some saved nanoseconds.

Comment: Also, validating in `primary` constructor ensures that your preconditions are always met, even when it is called from lets say `apply` method of `companion` object...